# Can DVD drives be used to set up a RAID system?

Tags: dvd, raid

Can SATA DVD drives be used to set up a [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) system? It is for setting up an experimental Video On Demand server where data can be striped over many DVDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it would work well.  I'm not certain, but I believe the DVD format breaks up movies into discrete file chapters and each chapter comprises a serial read file so random access to any one data position which would be necessary in order to do something like striping would be very difficult.  Note that this isn't verified.

The other issue is speed.  The ability for a drive to deliver head movement is slower than a normal hard drive so high speed transfer is affected.  Even the fastest drives only deliver about 30MB/sec compared to a single SATA 6Gig hard drive's 250MB/sec.